# Android SDK: APP_FOREGROUNDED and APP_BACKGROUNDED behaviors is never triggered

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, salesforce-sdk-android

So, I have implemented SFMCSDK inside Application onCreate() the way it is written in a documentation, also aligned code with sample projects and another project where functionality works as expected. SDK is initialized successfully and fully working - I receive push notifications, see statistics and etc.

The only thing which is not working is lifecycle callbacks, which is critical as we use in-app messages that is triggering when application goes to foreground.
I see by logs that `BehaviorManager` is initialized successfully and subscribed to `APP_BACKGROUNDED` and `APP_FOREGROUNDED` events. I also receive other kind of events - such as `SCREEN_ENTRY`, as well as `BEHAVIOR_CUSTOMER_PUSH_MESSAGING_TOGGLED`, `IDENTITY_UPDATED` and so on.

But `APP_BACKGROUNDED` and `APP_FOREGROUNDED` are never triggered, however they are critical for in-app messaging.

I would highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's JetPack AppStartup component and WorkManager are swallowing the lifecycle events and not passing them downstream to listeners/observers.

Add this to your manifest:

```
<provider

    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"

    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"

    android:exported="false"

    tools:node="merge">

    <meta-data

        android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"

        android:value="androidx.startup"

        android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"

        tools:node="remove" />

</provider>
```

Comment: I would tell you are hero, but you are more than a hero. This fixed the issue, much thanks to you!